# How to Download easy way to Android version 4.0 souce code

Tags: android

I want to download android version 4.0 source code for free to use in my own system in android
can u tell me how to download easily this code.

and which requirement to need for download.

Comment: Here's all the info you need:
http://source.android.com/source/index.html

Comment: can u done this thing and time.???

Comment: i have one concept ..???

Comment: do u try this thing any time..??? to download this code

Comment: Its pretty easy, all you need is a git client (in this example they used 'Repo') http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html

Once you have the checkout running it wont take so long.